# Parsing a table from website (choosing correct HTML tag)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I need to make dataframe from the following page: http://pitzavod.ru/products/upakovka/

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests
kre = requests.get(f'http://pitzavod.ru/products/upakovka/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(kre.text, 'lxml')
table1 = soup.find('table', id="tab3")
```

I chose "tab3", as I find in the HTML text <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab3". But the variable table1  gives no output. How can I get the table? Thank You.

Comment: There is no ```table``` with id ```tab3``` on the linked page just a ```div``` with this id.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>**NOTE:** you can get the table as a DataFrame in one statement with [`.read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html), but the [DataFrame returned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRDWm.png) by `pd.read_html('http://pitzavod.ru/products/upakovka/')[0]` will not retain line breaks.</sup>

*`.find('table', id="tab3")`* searches for **`table` tags with `id="tab3"`**, and there are no such elements in that page's HTML.

There's a **`div`** with [`id="tab3"`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ih7zh.png) (as you've notice), *but it does not contain any tables*.

The  [only table on the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwmiX.png) is contained in a `div` with **`id="tab4"`**, so you might have used *`table1 = soup.find('div', id="tab4").table`* [although I prefer using [`.select`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) with [CSS selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.php) for targeting nested tags].

---

Suggested solution:

```py
kre = requests.get('http://pitzavod.ru/products/upakovka/')
# print(kre.status_code, kre.reason, 'from', kre.url)
kre.raise_for_status()
soup = BeautifulSoup(kre.content, 'lxml')

# table = soup.select_one('div#tab4>div.table-responsive>table')
table = soup.find('table') # soup.select_one('table')
tData = [{
    1 if 'center' in c.get('style', '') else ci: '\n'.join([
        l.strip() for l in c.get_text('\n').splitlines() if l.strip()
    ]) for ci, c in enumerate(r.select('td'))
} for r in table.select('tr')]
df = pandas.DataFrame(tData)

## combine the top 2 rows to form header ##
df.columns = ['\n'.join([
    f'{d}' for d in df[c][:2] if pandas.notna(d)
]) for c in df.columns]
df = df.drop([0,1], axis='rows').reset_index(drop=True)

# print(df.to_markdown(tablefmt="fancy_grid"))
```

[image: fop]

<sub>(Normally, I would use [this function](https://pastebin.com/wQ0D6S3B) if I wanted to specify the separator for tag-contents inside cells, but the middle cell in the 2nd header row [would be shifted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8RGZ.png) if I used `.DataFrame(read_htmlTable(table, tSep='\n', asObj='dicts'))` - the *`1 if 'center' in c.get('style', '') else ci`* bit in the above code is for correcting that.)</sub>